# *.desktop file not starting java application on Slax9.3

Tags: shell-script, java, desktop

Hi I have installed a Java program.

If I put

```
/usr/local/TheNumberRace/start.sh
```

in the command line it starts.

I created the following *.desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=/usr/local/TheNumberRace/images/numberraceIcon64x64.png
Name=NumberRace
Exec=/usr/local/TheNumberRace/start.sh
```

I can find the Icon on the desktop but it will not start the program.
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/local/TheNumberRace/start.sh`?

Comment: root@slax:~# ls -l /usr/local/TheNumberRace/start.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 95 Sep 17 12:58 /usr/local/TheNumberRace/start.sh

Answer (score 2):

[Desktop entries need at least 2 keys](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html): `Type` and `Name`. Try adding `Type=Application` to your `.desktop` file.

By the way, it may not be your case but if the program you are trying to execute does not have a GUI, then it may appear that it never gets executed, but if you take a look to some program like `top` or `gnome-system-monitor` the process will be there.

Comment: Added "Type=Application" just before name. It make no difference.

Comment: @Creative Did you make it executable? `chmod u+x your_file`

Comment: yes I did that as well. I can start the program by double klick on the *.desktop file. But if I press on the Shortcut on XLunch nothing happens.

Comment: Just added the Program to the fluxbox menu. I can now start it from the fluxbox menu. Just wonder why it does not work from XLunch.